# screeps autospawner giving 'not defined' errors

Tags: javascript, screeps

I am trying to make a modular auto-spawner system where i just need to import the file to start spawning creeps of that role.

But what happens is that i get this error every tick.

```
ReferenceError: spawnInfo is not defined
    at Object.module.exports.loop (main:11:33)
    at __mainLoop:1:52
    at __mainLoop:2:3
    at Object.exports.evalCode (<runtime>:15851:76)
    at Object.exports.run (<runtime>:46474:24)
```

[My code](https://pastebin.com/u/taitep/1/ehdBuUxL)

Comment: The error code gives you good information where to look for the error. main file, line 11. Looks like spawnInfo variable is not defined.

Comment: Look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

The variable ‘spawnInfo’ is used but never defined. Check out line 11 for when it’s used.

After checking out the code I think ‘spawnInfo’ should be key (refering to the role)

Comment: sry, i do not understand. could you please send a fixed version of the code?

Comment: could you please send a working version of the code?